# Scalability of a Parallel MPI based Poisson Solver using Finite Difference Scheme

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, solver, poisson, finite-difference

I am developing a MPI based parallel numerical solver for a Laplace equation subjected to Dirichlet Boundary condition using Finite Difference method.I have taken a square computational domain with a grid size of 1024 x 1024. My objective is to evaluate the Scalability of the developed solver.

I have tested the code using 4,8,16,32,64,128 and 256 processors on a HPC facility having 8 nodes with each node consisting of 48 cores. Until 128 processors I could find a linear scalability in the computational time.(i.e between two consecutive cores say 4 and 8, 8 and 16, 16 and 32, 32 and 64 the solution converges and attains the set L2 and L-infinity true error norms values in the order of 10^-7 and 10^-8 without any issues and also the computational time reduces by half. whereas when i run the code using 128 and 256 cores the error norm values are not following a similar trend as that for 64 cores. The convergence rate drastically reduces say for 128 processors the error norm value is not reducing beyond 10^-6 and it takes more than half the computational time for 64 cores.Similarly with 256 cores the convergence rate is very poor and the computational time is very high.So, I request the experts in this field to help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: what if you try a 2048x2048 grid? can you scale beyond 128 processors?

Comment: And what if you try a `2^20 x 2^20` grid?  Think abut *weak scaling* and *strong scaling*.  They don't build them exascale computers so we can run wee `2^10` grids on them.

Comment: You don't actually say what your solver is. If that's a conjugate gradient method, the inner products will have numerical inaccuracies that are different per process count. Can you spot an error that starts appearing in the last digit, then last two, et cetera?

Comment: I am comparing the performance of point by point Gauss-Seidel, point by point red-black Gauss-Seidel, line by line TDMA, cyclic reduction(CR), parallel cyclic reduction(PCR), cr-pcr hybrid and pcr-thomas hybrid solvers. 
@Victor Eijkhout

Comment: Traditional GS has a recursion, so it's hard to parallelize. However see the Lois Adams / Harry Jordan paper. Line methods are also not parallel, unless you put a red/black on the lines. Thomas methods are just a silly name on a tri-diagonal (maybe dense banded) LU factorization. But none of these methods are any good. You should use an iterative methods such as Conjugate Gradients. In fact, you should use a *library* containing such methods. I advocate the PETSc library.